# Using stock photos for light swirls

Tags: background

I have licensed several 'light effects' photos from Adobestock.com that are AI files.  They are supposed to be transparent but they have a gray background that I am unable to remove.  How do i USE these files and incorporate them in a design?

Comment: If they are AI files, it's highly unlikely that these are "photos".   Photos come from cameras, and are raster. Illustrator is a vector image editor. Have you checked the layers?  There may be a background layer or a grey filled rectangle, which you could simply delete.

Comment: Like Billy Kerr has mentioned, and if you don't seem able to access layers, maybe try right-clicking and releasing the clipping mask. If you provide a screenshot of what the layers of your files look like, we may be in better position to help you.

Answer (score 0):

May be they have a **Simulate Colored Paper**.

Look for it at **File** > **Document Setup** and uncheck it.

[image]